# Using URL Parameters setting in Google Webmaster Tools to exclude temporary parameters

Tags: google-search-console, url-parameters

I'm checking out the URL Parameters Google Webmaster Tools to exclude certain URL parameters, but I have to be careful according to Google.

So here's my question:

Through this URL:

```
www.example.com/products
```

, a user can view all products on my site. When a user views all products on my site in a certain area, it would look like this:

```
www.example.com/products/chicago
```

But if a user searches on a location where no results are returned, e.g. on "london", I redirect the user to:

```
www.example.com/products?all=1
```

Where I use that temporary `all=1` parameter to show a messsage "no products found, we're now showing all products".

Parameter `all` only exists in the case no products are found and can only contain a value of `1` and no other value. I think it's safe to configure in Webmaster Tools that parameter "all" does not affect page content. I think in doing so, all URL's containing the parameter `all=1` will be ignored, but the original URL, in the above scenario `www.example.com/products`, will still be indexed and shown.
Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think it's safe to configure in Webmaster Tools that parameter "all" does not affect page content. I think in doing so, all URL's containing the parameter all=1 will be ignored

But Google's notification that follows appears to suggest otherwise:

> ... If many URLs differ only in this parameter, **Googlebot will crawl one representative URL.**

However, selecting "Yes" > "Other" > "No URLs". For which Google states: "Googlebot won't crawl any URLs containing this parameter." - would seem to be the desired result.

---

An alternative to using Google's URL parameters (which, after all, only affects Google) is to simply set the appropriate `rel="canonical"` element for the page. ie. `http://www.example.com/products`. This would be the preferred option.

Comment: Thanks..for now I think it's too confusing what this setting does so I won't risk using it. And I've looked into `rel=canonical` in the past, but that too was a bit confusing for me. E.g. when I set `rel=canonical` on `http://www.example.com/products`, relative to what is it canonical? To `http://www.example.com/products?all=1` (which is ok) or to `http://www.example.com/products/chicago` or even to `http://www.example.com/products?page=3&rows=4` (where I'd say for the latter 2 it would not be ok or desirable as they show different products).

Comment: The `<link rel="canonical"` element sets the canonical URL for the current URL/page. So, the canonical URL for the page `/products?all=1` is presumably `http://www.example.com/products` - is it not? `/products` is the page you want to see in the SERPs, not `/products?all=1`.